# Triggering event click() using document.querySelector() is not working, but triggering CSS event click() from console works ok

Tags: javascript

Triggering event `click()` using `document.querySelector()` is not working, but triggering CSS event `click()` from console works ok as follows:

```
$0.click(); // Works Ok
```

`$0` refers to the same element that `document.querySelector()`

```
const element = document.querySelector('.red')
element.click(); // Not Works
```

`element`:

```
<span color="foreground" class="red">Red</span>
```

`$0`:

```
<span color="foreground" class="red">Red</span>
```

How could click in the element using `document.querySelector()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Does it work ?

First of all, please note that triggering `$0.click()` in the console is not CSS but Javascript.

Also, calling your element with a querySelector and then triggering the click method works fine. Here is a basic example :

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector('.red').click()
}, 1000)
```

```html
<span class="red" onclick="console.log('clicked')">Text in a span</span>
```

### Why it could fail

You nay face different situations where your code do not works **as you expected**.

1- You may call your script before the page finished loading. In this case, the reference to document.querySelector will not find the element, and return null instead of the element. But when this happens, we get an error in the console.

2- You have several elements in your page with the class of "red". Then, you are probably clicking on an other element. In this case, nothing appears in the console.

Comment: You are right, there was more than one element that meet the condition, thank you very much